# Summarize all counts between deployments

Tags: graphite

We've got a system which writes some count metrics using a Counter from io.dropwizard.metrics java lib. The system is deployed once a day and our count metrics look in such way:

[image]

What I need is to summarize all that daily counts to a month value. Afterwards I'll show it as a single stat.
How can I do that?

Here is the query for the graph:

> sumSeries(mysys.{prod,production}.{server1,server2,server3}.important.metric.count))

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want for last 30 days - `summarize(nonNegativeDerivative(mysys.{prod,production}.{server1,server2,server3}.important.metric.count)), "30d", "sum", false)`

Or use `consolidateBy(integral(sumSeries(nonNegativeDerivative(mysys.{prod,production}.{server1,server2,server3}.important.metric.count))), 'max')` and set "Override relative time" in Grafana (it's on "Time range" tab in Graph's settings) for 30 days